# FFmpeg : ошибка [image2 @ 0000020b90eb2600] Could not open file : IM/01x01_00001.jpg av_interleaved_write_frame(): I/O error

Tags: ffmpeg

Столкнулся с такой вот проблемой: хотел перекодировать видео формата .mp4 в кучу кадров формата .jpg через программу ffmpeg, командой `ffmpeg -i Morty.mp4 -q:v 1 IM/01x01_%05d.jpg` , где (Morty название самого файла). Прога начала свою работу, однако позже выдала такую ошибку   `[image2 @ 0000020b90eb2600] Could not open file : IM/01x01_00001.jpg av_interleaved_write_frame(): I/O error` . Вопрос: что надо делать чтобы исправить эту ошибку и почему она появилась? Прилагаю скриншот всего процесса.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Папка IM существует?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Создал папку и дело пошло, спасибо большое, insolor!

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать другую команду: ffmpeg -i Morty.mp4 image%d.jpg

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]